# Does anybody know of a released API for Microsoft Vine?

Tags: social-networking

I have an idea for the newly announced Microsoft Vine, and I was wondering if there is a public API available. I have had no luck in searching, just a bunch of news articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can get into the private beta, my guess is "no".